# Convert Mangento module page to use a cms page

Tags: magento

I have a module that creates pages in Magento. Since I can't duplicate the functionality of the module in a CMS page, I want to convert the module to produce pages that use the CMS model for its page output. I was looking in the Controller and this code looks promising, but I not sure what I would change. Can anyone help me?

```
        // Setup layout handles
    $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()
        ->addHandle('default')
        ->addHandle('custompage_map');

    $this->addActionLayoutHandles();

    $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
    $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();

    foreach (array('catalog/session', 'checkout/session') as $class_name) {
        $storage = Mage::getSingleton($class_name);
        if ($storage) {
            $this->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->addMessages($storage->getMessages(true));
        }
    }

    // Render our layout
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look @

> /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php

Replace your controller method with

```
public function noRouteAction($coreRoute = null)
{
    $pageId = {cms page key};
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }
}
```